# I want to join 3 tables with a common column using join and or condition In MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join, union

I have 3 tables - Profiles, Product , Service

Profile has a field document_id,VendorName whose is linked with product (field - author) and service (field - author).

Profiles: few document id are linked with product, few are linked with service, few are linked with both, and few are linked with none.

I want output as

```
____________________________________
VendorName  Product      Service
ABC         Fruits         -
            Vegetables     -
            Cereals      Selling
DEF           -            -
GHI           -         Plumbing
______________________________________
```

I have written the following query, but it isn't correct:

```
select DISTINCT Profiles.document_id as Document_ID,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Product.Data,'$.author'),
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Services.Data,'$.author'),
ifnull(concat(UPPER(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Profiles.DATA,'$.firstName')) , ' ', upper(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Profiles.DATA,'$.lastName'))),"-")  AS VendorName,
ifnull(UPPER(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Product.DATA, '$.category')),"-") as productCategory,
ifnull(UPPER(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Services.DATA, '$.category')),"-") as ServiceCategory
FROM
`roque-prod.profiles.profiles_raw_latest` as Profiles
JOIN
`roque-prod.roqueprod.roque_raw_latest` as Product
ON
Profiles.document_id = JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Product.Data,'$.author')
OR
JOIN 
services.services_raw_latest as Services
ON
Profiles.document_id = JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Services.Data,'$.author')
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error running query: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword JOIN at [17:1]

I tried using `union` as well, but it is not serving my purpose correctly. With `union` all the products and services are combined into one field, which means all the records of products are clubbed with service. But I want that the fields should be in different columns (please check mentioned output).

```
--> For Union I used the following query
select Profiles.document_id as Document_ID,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Product.Data,'$.author'),
ifnull(concat(UPPER(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Profiles.DATA,'$.firstName')) , ' ', upper(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Profiles.DATA,'$.lastName'))),"-")  AS VendorName,
ifnull(UPPER(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Product.DATA, '$.category')),"-") as productCategory,
FROM
`roque-prod.profiles.profiles_raw_latest` as Profiles
JOIN
`roque-prod.roqueprod.roque_raw_latest` as Product
ON
Profiles.document_id = JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Product.Data,'$.author')

UNION all

select Profiles.document_id as Document_ID,

JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Services.Data,'$.author'),
ifnull(concat(UPPER(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Profiles.DATA,'$.firstName')) , ' ', upper(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Profiles.DATA,'$.lastName'))),"-")  AS VendorName,
ifnull(UPPER(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Services.DATA, '$.category')),"-") as ServiceCategory
FROM
`roque-prod.profiles.profiles_raw_latest` as Profiles
JOIN 
services.services_raw_latest as Services
ON
Profiles.document_id = JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Services.Data,'$.author')
```

Comment: "it isn't correct" is not a problem description. Explain what happens, show the output, and why that is wrong.

Comment: Output I have shown above the Code there are 3 fields VendorName, Product and Service.
I am getting the following error:
Error running query: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword JOIN

Comment: Please [edit] the question to tag which implementation of SQL you're using (Server? My? PostGres?) and quote the error in full including any line/column number it implicates.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: So the query that is currently in the question is the one that gives the error? What about how you tried using `union`; what code was that, and what was 'not correct' about it?

Comment: You need to use `LEFT JOIN` to get `NULL` if there's no matching row coming from a `JOIN`.

Comment: You can't write `OR JOIN`. There's no such thing as a conditional JOIN. Write different queries that join with each table, then combine them with UNION.

Comment: Can you show the original data that should produce the results you show?

Comment: @underscore_d I have edited the question again.

Comment: @barmar I already tried using union but what happens is that All the records of product and services are clubbed into one column , I want them as different fields.

Comment: This isn't going well. It's almost hopeless to assume it won't get worse, but while there's hope.. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

To get the fields of a union in different columns, put empty "dummy" values in each subquery for the data that comes from the other subquery. The general structure should be:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT common_col1, common_col2, ..., table1_col1, table1_col2, ..., '-' AS table2_col1, '-' AS table2_col2, ...
    FROM table1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT common_col1, common_col2, ..., '=' AS table1_col1, '-' AS table1_col2, ..., table2_col1, table2_col2, ...
    FROM table2
) AS x
ORDER BY common_col1, common_col2, ...
```

Comment: There are few records which are present in both the tables.